# Binding an ObservableCollection to a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to bind an `ObservableCollection` (C#) to a `ComboBox` (XAML).  A million articles, question/answers, and posts on the internet suggest that this is a totally simple task.  So far, I have to disagree with them:

**XAML**

```
<Window
    x:Class     = "ComboTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns       = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x     = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title       = "MainWindow"
    Height      = "350"
    Width       = "525"
    DataContext = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox 
            Name          = "URICombo"
            ItemsSource   = "{Binding URIs}" 
            SelectedIndex = "0">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**C#**

```
namespace ComboTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class URIPairing
        {
            public string URI  { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public URIPairing(string _Name, string _URI)
            {
                this.Name = _Name;
                this.URI  = _URI;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<URIPairing> URIs { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            this.URIs = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<URIPairing>();
            this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing( "DEV"     , "Some URL" ));
            this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing( "SANDBOX" , "Some URL" ));
            this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing( "QA"      , "Some URI" ));
        }
    }
}
```

***When run, the application shows a simple, empty ComboBox.***

Debugging shows that the `ObservableCollection` is populating correctly, and looking at Visual Studio's "Apply Data Binding..." panel, I can see that the DataContext is null and that no paths are available to bind to.

[image: Apply Data Binding dialog box]

I sincerely hope that I'm not making some silly typo (I've copy/pasted every like-namespace I can find with no luck); I'm at an absolute loss, otherwise, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that didn't work is because you don't have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented in your `MainWindow`. When you did a binding to the `DataContext` to `RelativeSource Self` on the Window, initially when you run the application it tried to grab the `URIs` property which is not yet set and then you reset the `DataContext` in the constructor to `this` which would mark it as new one and it is already late, thus you need to call `INPC`.

An easy and cleaner fix is to remove either the setting of the `DataContext` in the constructor or the binding in the `XAML` but not both.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Implementation of the INPC
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public class URIPairing
    {
        public string URI  { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public URIPairing(string _Name, string _URI)
        {
            this.Name = _Name;
            this.URI  = _URI;
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<URIPairing> _uris;
    public ObservableCollection<URIPairing> URIs { get { return _uris; } set { _uris = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        this.URIs = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<URIPairing>();
        this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing( "DEV"     , "Some URL" ));
        this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing( "SANDBOX" , "Some URL" ));
        this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing( "QA"      , "Some URI" ));
    }
}
```

This will propagate the new value to the `User Interface`.

Comment: Got this working using a pretty generic `OnPropertyChanged`.  I feel pretty silly about missing this now.  Thanks!

Comment: If I messaged you a copy of my `OnPropertyChanged` function would you be willing to add it to the question for future readers?

Comment: I can add that now. Updated it with better implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set `DataContext` to itself:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = this;
}
```

**OR**

May be in XAML:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Of course your combobox declaration should be this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding URIs}"/>
```

---

**UPDATE** (For anyone who stumbled upon this post in future)

Generally bindings are done with ViewModels, so I don't feel any UI component should implement `INPC`. But, that's completely opinion based.

Anyhow if you set `DataContext` from XAML, it wasn't working because XAML gets parsed with line `InitializeComponent()` but at that time list wasn't initialized so binding fails silently (you can check that in Output window of VS2010, you will see binding failure message over there).

That being said, if you want it to work from XAML as well (without implementing INPC), all you have to do is initialize list before `InitializeComponent()` and it will work from both sides.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        URIs = new ObservableCollection<URIPairing>();
        InitializeComponent();

        this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing("DEV", "Some URL"));
        this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing("SANDBOX", "Some URL"));
        this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing("QA", "Some URI"));
    }
```

Comment: Neither of these worked =\ They should be in their, though, so I'll add them to the original question.

Comment: You show two declaration of ComboBox in question. One with `ItemsSource="{Binding URIs}"` and other with `ItemsSource="{Binding}". It should be first.

Comment: (in response to edit) ah, yes, that must have gotten dropped out when I messed with the "Apply Data Binding..." panel.  The compiled version is as it appears in the StackOverflow code view and not as it appears in the image, though.

Comment: Perhaps some feature that I'm losing by using VS2010.  It's good to have your information, too, but it did not solve my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Issue was you was setting `DataContext` from both sides. I mentioned OR in comment and not both. Omit from XAML and set only in code behind and it will work without `INPC`. Anyhow if it is solved then it's fine. Have a good day.. :)

Comment: It works when I set it on only the C# side but not on only the XAML side which suggests the same ongoing problem.  As it turns out the larger project that I trimmed this from uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` anyway, so it's the best answer for me, but the +3 you have makes sense, yours is also an excellent answer.

Comment: @Sandy - Yeah it won't work from XAML without `INPC` because XAML is parsed when `InitializeComponent()` gets called and till then list is null so binding fails silently. If before `InitializeComponent()` you initialize the list `URIs = new ObservableCollection<URIPairing>();` then it will work from XAML as well and that too without INPC.

Comment: I'm learning a huge amount from this question (I'm not exactly a C# wizard, here).  Thanks!

Comment: That's what this forum is for :) Anyhow I updated that in answer to help anyone who stumbled upon this post in future.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the main part assigning to the combobox.

```
        this.URIs = new stem.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<URIPairing>();
         this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing("DEV", "Some URL"));
        this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing("SANDBOX", "Some URL"));
        this.URIs.Add(new URIPairing("QA", "Some URI"));
        URICombo.ItemsSource = URIs;
        URICombo.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

Comment: This worked! (but only after removing the binding from the XAML, it threw an error when it was defined in both places).  Any idea why I'm only able to bind it from the C# side?

Comment: If you're gonna use this what's the point of the binding? Just set it explicitly. You want to use a ViewModel with Bindings

Comment: Because you have not implemented MVVM properly

Comment: @lll It's true, and I'm currently reviewing your answer (which would be the preferred way for me).  If I can get it working it's definitely the path I'd like to go down.